# The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

I have a problem. My code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point[] points = {
            new Point(10, 20),
            new Point(100, 200),
            new Point(400, 500)
        };
        Point first = Array.Find(points, pointFind);
        Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}, {1}", first.X, first.Y);
        Console.Read();
    }
    private static bool pointFind(Point point)
    {
        if (point.X % 2 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Maybe this program is wrong but I don't know why I have a bug "The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?". I have "using System.Drawing" but it's not helpful for me.

Comment: And is the `System.Drawing.dll` in among the references of your project?

Comment: Can this even compile? Maybe I'm stupid, but it doesn't look like you are are calling `pointsFind` correctly...

Comment: I used it. I added reference like said roryap and is good!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `using System.Drawing`, you need to *reference* the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly.

If your project is a console application or anything other than a WinForms application, that assembly isn't reference by default when you create a new project.

[MSDN for adding a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You can either change Point to System.Drawing.Point or add this line to the top:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but did you read the question? He knows this and has this directive in his code already.

Comment: I used it and nothing.